# Why is my fresh Ubuntu install (from USB drive) stuck on a blank screen with a blinking cursor?

Tags: boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I am about to use Ubuntu for the first time and I have successfully installed it from my USB drive. However, in the process of installation, my laptop has been on a blank screen with a blinking cursor for almost six hours. Whatever the heck is going on? Even if I restart, it goes back to that mode.

Am I being impatient or will it remain so for eternity? What should I do now?

Comment: Sometimes the download gets corrupted because it is one big file from one source.  A more reliable download comes from using the torrent file. See here for details: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads

Comment: At what point in the process does this happen? What's on the screen just before this starts?

Comment: Give photos or video